# QGIS rule-based filtering not working

Tags: qgis, rendering, rule-based

I'm having a problem with rule-based filtering in QGIS.  I created a rule and tested it, and it showed that it gets hits.  Below shows the attributes to which I wish to apply the rules:

[image: Attribute table of layer to which rules apply]

The following shows the rule for matching fences, and which, when tested, successfully matches against the 7 fence layers:

[image: Fence matching rule]

But when I try to use the rules, none of the fences are matched, as shown in the overall test of the rules here:

[image: But the fences are not matched]

What's interesting is that "Creek" matches and it's only a single word.  It's almost as if the '%' wildcard characters are getting ignored for the fence rules when they are actually put to use, but work when the rule is tested by itself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use the strpos function ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "simpler", but this kind of use of ILIKE is documented in several places for rule-based filtering for qgis as examples of finding a substring within a string.

Moreover, I find it puzzling that in one case it matches, and the same exact rule fails to find matches when put to us. That's inconsistent behavior.

**Followup**, I tried `strpos()`, which worked.  So, thanks for the nudge, but I'm still puzzled by why `ILIKE` didn't work.

Comment: "ILIKE" is the case-sensitive version of "LIKE" , I thought you were using "LIKE" and it was just the expression being wonky but that explain things now. For fences the capitalisation matches so it works, though Creek shouldn't be working.

Comment: Your data seems to contain line breaks at the end and the %-wildcard doesn't seem to work with them.